# QPrinter rounds pagesize if it is close to the standard page sizes (A3, A4 ...)

Tags: qt, qprinter

I want to save and restore QPrinter::pagesize for PageSize::Custom.
But when I save size, I read strange rounding size:

```
QPrinter p;
for(int i=0; i<20000; ++i) {
    QSizeF size( qreal(rand()%100000)/100, qreal(rand()%100000)/100 );

    p.setPaperSize( size, QPrinter::Millimeter );

    if( size != p.paperSize(QPrinter::Millimeter) ) 
        qDebug() << size <<  "->" << p.paperSize(QPrinter::Millimeter);
}
```

> QSizeF(216.48, 321.33) -> QSizeF(215.9, 322.3)
>   QSizeF(250.15, 352.36) -> QSizeF(250, 353)
>   QSizeF(178.75, 227.77) -> QSizeF(177.8, 228.6) // 178.75 - 177.8 = 0.95 !!!
>   QSizeF(321.24, 445.22) -> QSizeF(322, 445)
>   QSizeF(182.6, 258.4) -> QSizeF(182, 257) // 258.4 - 257 = 1.4 !!!
>   QSizeF(382.17, 279.77) -> QSizeF(381, 279.4)
>   QSizeF(111.1, 208.13) -> QSizeF(110, 208) // 111.1 - 110 = 1.1 !!!
>   QSizeF(32.32, 43.67) -> QSizeF(32, 45)
>   QSizeF(114.07, 163.04) -> QSizeF(114, 162)
>   QSizeF(228.5, 323.36) -> QSizeF(229, 324)
>   QSizeF(63.81, 92.1) -> QSizeF(64, 91)

11 values have terrible rounding, and ~20000 values are valid.

Size rounded to standard (A0, A4 ......)
If its width and height differ by any standard size less than ~ 1.2

How disable it? Example code with problem: (freeze 210 value)

```
QDoubleSpinBox sb;
sb.setRange(0.0, 300.0);
sb.setValue(210.0);
sb.show();

QObject::connect(&sb, qOverload<double>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),[&sb](double value){
    QPrinter pr;
    pr.setPaperSize( QSizeF(value, 297.0), QPrinter::Millimeter );
    sb.blockSignals(true);
    sb.setValue( pr.paperSize(QPrinter::Millimeter).width() );
    sb.blockSignals(false);
});
```

Comment: why I ask it.   
open QtCreator; press Print; set page size: A4; set page size Custom;
Widht and height spinbox not worked by mouse scroll !!!
because 209,211 rounded to 210.

Answer (score 0):

QT5:
`void setPaperSize(QPrinter::PaperSize newPaperSize)` is [obsolete.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter-obsolete.html#paperSize)

This is a wild guess:
QT uses predefined sizes and `PaperSize paperSize()` returns the "nearest" one. See [this link here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpagesize.html#PageSizeId-enum) but is not well programmed -> obsolete.

Comment: Ok. Widht and height spinbox not worked by mouse scroll in QtCreator.
Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Better ask a new question with details what you have done and the code for creating the spinbox and everything surounding it. But a guess would be that an other widget is above your spinbox so that its stealing focus.

Comment: The problem is not in my code(I made a similar printer setup widget) . Look at my comment on the question.
QtCreator also has this bug or feature.
Do I need to correct the problem or accept?

Comment: I think Qt uses the default print dialog from your OS. I am using Windows 10 and i don't even have the possibility to change the sizes.
So i would try to print from other applictions like notepad++ and try to change the value there, if it still fails my 1st step would be checking for system updates or outdated drivers.

Comment: Under -options -Designer you can change your print preview. Try another one.